# Outlook Web Add-In: Display reply form with current mail item's attachments

Tags: javascript, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

When you click "Reply" in outlook, it doesn't preserve the attachments, so I'm working on a web add-in "Reply With Attachments" - Upon clicking my add-in button, a new reply window should be open, and the attachments of the selected mail item should be attached to that reply window.
According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-messageread-displayreplyform-member(1)), this is how you display a reply form with attachments:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm(
{
    'htmlBody' : 'hi',
    'attachments' :
    [
        {
            'type' : Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentType.File,
            'name' : 'squirrel.png',
            'url' : 'http://i.imgur.com/sRgTlGR.jpg'
        }
    ]
});
```

but is it possible to add attachments to the reply form in a way other than specifying the URL? I already have the attachments of the current email in code:

```
let attachments = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments;
```

One approach I thought of is to upload the attachments to file storage system (Egnyte), and then specify each file's URL in the 'url' property of an attachment, but then I would have to temporarily make those files public, and delete them after adding them to reply form. But I don't want to make sensitive files public, even temporarily. And also this approach seems like overkill for something so simple and straightforward.
Any ideas?

Comment: Here are some ways to fetch attachments- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I don't see how that would help me.. Like I said in the post, I already have the attachments in js: let attachments = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments;
But the displayReplyForm() method needs attachment URL, but I just want to attach current mailbox item's attachments to the new reply form, not remotely hosted attachment. I couldn't find any example on MS forums where that's done.. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature: add attachments of current item via displayReplyForm API without a temporary save, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.